# Symfony2.6.1 can't install it, cmd doesn't recognize php

Tags: php, symfony, installation

I'm following a tutorial to get started with symfony. On that tutorial they show you were the download link is for symfony. But once i go on the website :
http://symfony.com/download
there is no download link. I guess they removed it.

They show you how to install it via CMD commands.

```
Installation on Windows
c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

So i try that, but they don't recognize "php" as intern command.

I tried to run the cmd on administrator mode it didn't change.

I know there is something about the environment variables, that i should put PHP in it. But now i try to run symfony on my wamp server, so do i have to link it with wamp ?

Comment: Do you have a cli version of [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php) installed?

Comment: No, but i just found a tutorial that explains how to do it. I should go for that ? Will it work with wamp ?

Comment: Yep.  Windows won't know what the command `php ...` should do if it's not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried that error what I did is that I instead of C:> you need to go to
C:\xampp\php:> and there set the path

```
C:\xampp\php:\> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php
```

then after this you go to path where you wan to save your project.
I hope this helps.

Comment: yes that's what i did, but apparently composer is a good alternative too if you want to add more things to your symfony !

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, i suggest you using Composer: [Composer page](https://getcomposer.org/)

In the installation process, Composer ask to you for the php route (in xampp dir for example) and then windows cmd could be execute the php command.

Comment: Yes thanks ! I found out about composer and also how to put php in my global variables it works thanks :)